# Trying to learn methods/boolean. Need an assist

Tags: java

Trying to figure out what's wrong with my code here - I want user input to be checked with the concentrations array and if they enter any of the array to print out a positive display message... However, I get an output of "Yes, that is a valid concentration" every time, regardless of input.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class BASIT_Concentration_Check
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] concentrations = {"DTP","HCIT","INFS","NTEL","WDM"};
        String studentconcentration = getStudentConcentration();
        boolean concentrationvalid = isConcentrationValid(studentconcentration, concentrations);
        displayMessage(concentrationvalid);
    }

    public static String getStudentConcentration()
    {
        String studentconcentration = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is your B.S. AIT Concentration?");
        return studentconcentration;
    }

    public static boolean isConcentrationValid(String studentconcentration, String [] concentrations)
    {
        boolean concentrationvalid=false;
        for (int i=0;i<concentrations.length;i++)
        {
            if (concentrations[i]==studentconcentration)
                {
                    concentrationvalid = true;
                }
        }
        return concentrationvalid;
    }

    public static void displayMessage(boolean concentrationvalid)
    {
        if (concentrationvalid==true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yes, that is a valid concentration");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I'm sorry, that is not a valid concentration");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (concentrations[i]==studentconcentration)`

**That is not how you compare strings in Java!**

Instead use `if (concentrations[i].equals(studentconcentration))`

Basically, `==` only compares **references** (or values for **primitive** types), for a more detailed description of why it is this way, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: This doesn't explain why he's getting "Yes, that is valid" every time.  It would explain why he would get "Its not valid" every time, but that's not the case.

Comment: @MrTi That's true, in that case the problem is not reproducible. Which means that the OP has most likely not copied **the code, all the code and nothing but the code.** or not given enough details. Or mistakenly wrote the wrong message in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comparison error. In Java, using `==` operator fails with strings since strings are not primitive types, they are objects. So you have to use the `equals` method of the String class, like this.

```
if (concentrations[i].equals(studentconcentration))
```

This should work. Also you can add a `break;` statement if the validation is true to save some cpu processing. One more thing, there is no need to add `== true` in the if comparison of booleans, you can just use

```
if (concentrationvalid)
```

The above statement is the same as with your statement but is more readable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `.equals()` to compare strings in Java. It will return a boolean value of true or false which would activate the `if` statement if true or skip it if false.

You can also use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`  if you want the comparison to ignore whether the letters are upper/lower case.

Ex:

```
if (concentrations[i].equals(studentconcentration))
```

or

```
if (concentrations[i].equalsIgnoreCase(studentconcentration))
```

Hope that helps!